# Middlewares Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Soy nuevo en laravel y tengo un  problema de redirecciones me sale este mensaje en la página:

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Esto sucede cuando pongo la validación de required,si lo quito sí funciona me podrían decir por qué?:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class ValidateFields
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $validate =Validator::make($request->all(),[
            "email"=>"email",
             "password"=>"required"
            ]
        );

        if ($validate->fails()) {
          return redirect("login")->withErrors($validate);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Viste en algún tutorial que debías usar `return redirect("login")->withErrors($validate);`? Porque sin saber Laravel me suena como que (si ya falló la validación) es inútil volver a ejecutar la validación. Ésta necesariamente volverá a fallar.  Debiera haber un método `$validate->getLastError()` como para informarle al usuario que su login falló, pero no pasarle el mismo $validate al método `->withErrors()`

Comment: Sí,de laravel ya conozco muchas cosas le he estado dando duro,por cierto...aquí lo que busco es que se validen los campos y posteriormente si falla se envien las razones del fallo y se redireccione al login porque a él se accede por GET y no POST,POST sería para ya enviar los datos.

Comment: Cuando se llama a este validador? quizá la ruta "login" envía los datos a este mismo validador :P

Comment: ¿algún motivo para no validar en el Request?

Comment: Esto lo hice con el comando make::auth lo raro es que como digo si le quito el required me funciona,si lo dejo me sale el problema de las redirecciones,por cierto...lo hice de esta manera para practicar,porque se podría haber hecho sin un middlware.

Comment: Bueno...lo he "corregido" consultando cual es el método que lleva la petición ya que no me había dado cuenta que este middleware se aplica siempre para POST Y GET,gracias a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque parece que ya está solucionado, ¿por qué no utilizas el scaffold de autenticación de Laravel 5.

```
php composer make:auth
```

Con eso tendrás todo lo que necesitas, login, registro, forgot password y sus validaciones correspondiente.

Comment: Sí eso hice,he utilizado make:auth solo que quiero hacer que antes que consulte las credenciales y las contraste con las que se encuentran en base de datos le informe al usuario si escribió mal su correo o no,esto porque en el LoginController no existe dicho filtro.